# Python Scraping Error - You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.``3945.88 Safari/537.37"
url = 'https://emetonline.org/events/past-events/'
data = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'lxml')

events = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'col-12')
event_name = events.find('h4')  ->here's the error

print(event_name.text)
```

and the error is like that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\90507\Desktop\adsad.py", line 12, in <module>
    event_name = events.find('h4')
  File "C:\Users\90507\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2173, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to loop over each event when you use find_all

Comment: Well, where the error message says "ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element.", what do you think that means? Where it says "Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?", did you try to answer that question? What is the answer you came up with for that question? Did that give you an idea about how to change the code? What happened when you tried making that change to the code? (Hint: on the previous line, what do you expect `events` to end up looking like?)

Comment: And if you won't read an error message, why should we trust that you will read any answer we give you?

Comment: I found the linked duplicates by copying and pasting `ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?` into a search engine. In the future, please at least try this much. On Stack Overflow you are [expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to make an attempt to solve the problem yourself, and I literally can't think of any simpler things to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to loop over each event when you use find_all

Here is how you solve it:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.``3945.88 Safari/537.37"
url = 'https://emetonline.org/events/past-events/'
data = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'lxml')

events = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'col-12')
for event in events:
    event_name = event.find('h4')
    print(event_name.text)
```